Mirror Reflection In GLB format
I have tried to export mirror reflection PBR. It's visible in Blender, but I couldn't export as GLB. Also I tried in babylonjs (Plugin) via export but that also doesn't work. Is there any specific way to export the mirror Reflection. Currently I'm using GLB format because of web based work. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

For a mirror, set BaseColor to white, Metallic to 1.0, and Roughness to 0.0.
This will export to glTF PBR, but remember that the reflection environment in Blender will not get saved into the exported glTF file.  You'll need to set up a proper IBL environment in the framework that loads the GLB file.  And without pathtracing or ray tracing, you won't see reflections of geometry, just the environment.  If you need real-time mirroring of geometry on the web, you will need to implement that in your WebGL / WebGPU framework of choice, outside of Blender.


Thanks, for Mirror effect will taking only the HDR environment. Its not reflecting the opposite object.

Blender offers two kind of light probes to simulate mirror reflections: Spherical and Planar. The issue when exporting to GLB is that the format does not allow using such kind of probes by default.
However, Verge3D addon offers such capability by providing support for the special S8S_v3d_light_probes extension. This extension allows you to render Blender light probes with WebGL easily. Here is the tutorial on how to use this feature.
